# A confusing formula in Clifford algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, exterior-algebra, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I am reading a book named "An Introduction to Clifford Algebras and Spinors" by J. Vaz Jr. and R. da Rocha. In page 78, I met a confusing formula (3.89), written as:

$$\gamma(\mathbf{v})\gamma(\mathbf{u})=\gamma[\gamma(\mathbf{v})(\mathbf{u})]$$

where $\gamma:V\to\mathcal{C}\ell(V,g)$ is a Clifford mapping and $\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u}\in V$. The book said this formula is due to "the associativity of Clifford algebra".

I really don't understand this, could anyone give some hints of why?

### Context:

In the preceding section the authors constructed Clifford algebra using creation operators $\mathbf{E}:V\to\mathrm{End}(\bigwedge(V))$ where $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{v})(A)=\mathbf{v}\wedge A$, and annihilation operators $\mathbf{I}:V^*\to\mathrm{End}(\bigwedge(V))$ where $\mathbf{I}(\alpha)(A)=\alpha\rfloor A$. Using notation $\flat:V\to V^*$ as the index lowering operator, the Clifford mapping is defined as

$$\gamma=\gamma_+=\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{I}\circ\flat$$

After that confusing formula, the authors used above formula to get ($g$ is the associated bilinear quadratic form)

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma(\mathbf{v})(\mathbf{u})&=&(\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{I}\circ\flat)(\mathbf{v})(\mathbf{u})\\
&=&\mathbf{v}\wedge\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}_\flat\rfloor\mathbf{u}\\
&=&\mathbf{v}\wedge\mathbf{u}+g(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u})
\end{eqnarray}$$

And, thus

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma(\mathbf{v})\gamma(\mathbf{u})&=&\gamma[\gamma(\mathbf{v})(\mathbf{u})]\\
&=&\gamma[\mathbf{v}\wedge\mathbf{u}+g(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u})]\\
&=&\gamma(\mathbf{v}\wedge\mathbf{u})+g(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u})\mathbf{1}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: I'm confused by part of the definition of $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf I$ but I'm probably making incorrect assumptions. I assume $V$ is a vector space and $\text{End}(V)$ is the set of endomorphisms on $V$, i.e. linear functions $V\to V$. But then $\mathbf E(\mathbf v)(A)\notin V$, similarly for $\mathbf I$, at least for my usual understanding of $\wedge$ and $\rfloor$, but that also probably doesn't match the definitions being used here.

Comment: Despite the above confusions, it does seem to me that $\gamma(\mathbf u)(\mathbf v)$ is a round-about way to write the geometric product and so if $(\gamma(\mathbf u)\gamma(\mathbf v))(\mathbf w)$ means $\gamma(\mathbf u)(\gamma(\mathbf v)(\mathbf w))$, then the formula is indeed associativity of the geometric product. If we write $\gamma(\mathbf u)(\mathbf v)$ as simply $\mathbf u\mathbf v$, then the formula (applied to $\mathbf w$) is $\mathbf u(\mathbf v\mathbf w)=(\mathbf u\mathbf v)\mathbf w$.

Comment: My mistake, $\mathrm{End}(V)$ should be $\mathrm{End}(\bigwedge(V))$.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: So, do you have any idea about that formula? I cannot understand how that could hold. @DerekElkins

Comment: Well there's still something a bit off. $\gamma(\mathbf u)(\mathbf v)\notin V$, so $\gamma(\gamma(\mathbf u)(\mathbf v))$ doesn't make sense. Maybe the use of square brackets has some significance here that I'm not aware of, or maybe $\gamma$ is implicitly lifted to an outermorphism(?)

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm confused, maybe I should just ignore this formula and go on.

Comment: Okay, then we are confused together. It may just be a typo, but even then you should figure out what it *should* be. It doesn't seem like a typo though, at least from your summarization, so it's probably pretty important for the remainder to understand what is going on here, as similar things will likely occur later in the text. You should edit the question to highlight that the "type mismatch" is the source of your confusion. Can you provide the definition of the subscript $+$ notation, i.e. $\gamma_+$? That might make the intent clearer (or might not).

Comment: It seems that $\gamma$ satisfy some functional properties, removing parenthesis we get $\gamma\mathbf{v}\gamma\mathbf{u}=(\gamma\mathbf{v})\gamma\mathbf{u}=\gamma(\gamma\mathbf{v})\mathbf{u}$, but I still don't understand this. There is a $+$ because the authors also define a $\gamma_-=\mathbf{E}-\mathbf{I}\circ\flat$.

Comment: If the authors have simply said that $\gamma$ is (lifted to) an associative operations a la $\gamma(A)(\gamma(B)(C))=\gamma(\gamma(A)(B))(C)$, then there is nothing to say. The equation is a given. A better perspective on this might be $\gamma(\gamma(A)(B))=\gamma(A)\circ\gamma(B)$. A geometric algebra can be generated from a vector space by simply considering an associative, bilinear operation subject only to the equation $\mathbf u^2$ is a scalar for all vectors $\mathbf u$. The interior and exterior products can then be derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the original author via email and finally understand the formula. So let me share my understanding below.

Suppose we have an associative operator $\vartriangle$, satisfying
$$(\mathbf{v}\vartriangle\mathbf{u})\vartriangle\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{v}\vartriangle\mathbf{u}\vartriangle\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{v}\vartriangle(\mathbf{u}\vartriangle\mathbf{w})$$

So here if $\mathbf{v}\vartriangle\mathbf{u}=\gamma(\mathbf{v})(\mathbf{u})$, then we have
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma[\gamma(\mathbf{v})(\mathbf{u})](\mathbf{w})&=&(\mathbf{v}\vartriangle\mathbf{u})\vartriangle\mathbf{w}\\
&=&\mathbf{v}\vartriangle(\mathbf{u}\vartriangle\mathbf{w})\\
&=&\gamma(\mathbf{v})(\gamma(\mathbf{u})(\mathbf{w}))\\
&=&\gamma(\mathbf{v})\gamma(\mathbf{u})(\mathbf{w})
\end{eqnarray}$$

Removing $\mathbf{w}$ from both sides, we finally get
$$\gamma(\mathbf{v})\gamma(\mathbf{u})=\gamma[\gamma(\mathbf{v})(\mathbf{u})]$$

And the associativity is due to Clifford algebra.